# How do I find the longest prefix of any pair of strings in a set of N strings

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of N strings:
["pack", "packing", "banana", "banana pie", "banana smoothie"]

What is the theoretically/asymptotically most optimal approach for finding the two strings which share the longest prefix? In the example, `banana`  would be the longest prefix (shared by the 4th and 5th strings).

Comment: Hover the downvote button. One downvote reason is: _"This question does not show any research effort"_

Comment: @jabaa That's because I asked it before and mentioned some ideas, and everyone just posted my ideas back to me with no additional research effort on their part. I was hoping to get a little bit of creativity in the answers to help inspire me and get me to think about the problem differently.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and find the deepest node(s) which have at least 2 leafs. I have a hard time seeing how you would beat that.

Answer (score 2):

Asymptotically, the worst case is Θ(N), where N is the total length.  It's not hard to think of a case in which you'd have to examine almost all the characters, so the lower bound is easy.  There are lots of algorithms to demonstrate the upper bound.

A trie works, as Mikael suggests, but probably the fastest way would be to modify a MSB-first radix sort.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, I'll have to look into it some more, thanks.